# cannot convert value of type [anyhashable: any] to [string: any]

Tags: swift

```
 let darkGray = UIColor.darkGray
    let lightGray = UIColor.lightGray
    let white = UIColor.white
    // Navigation bar background.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = darkGray
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = lightGray
    // Color of typed text in the search bar.
    let searchBarTextAttributes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(UIFont.systemFontSize))]
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = searchBarTextAttributes as! [String : Any]
    // Color of the placeholder text in the search bar prior to text entry.
    let placeholderAttributes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(UIFont.systemFontSize))]
    // Color of the default search text.
    // NOTE: In a production scenario, "Search" would be a localized string.
    let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString( string: "Search", attributes: placeholderAttributes)
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

In the let attributedPlaceholder I'm coming up with an error, wondering if someone could shed some light on this for me?

Comment: The error is pretty clear – you have a `[AnyHashable: Any]` which you're trying to pass to a `[String : Any]`. Annotate `placeholderAttributes` as a `[String : Any]` instead.

Comment: Ahh thank you, makes sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let placeholderAttributes: [AnyHashable: Any] = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(UIFont.systemFontSize))]
    // Color of the default search text.
    // NOTE: In a production scenario, "Search" would be a localized string.
    let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString( string: "Lookup", attributes: placeholderAttributes as? [String: Any])
```

This worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can replace your code with this:

```
let placeholderAttributes = ["NSForegroundColorAttributeName": UIColor.white, "NSFontAttributeName": UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(UIFont.systemFontSize))]
// equivalent of: let placeholderAttributes: [String: Any?] = ...
let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString( string: "Search", attributes: placeholderAttributes)
```

Because you cannot convert `AnyHashable` to `String`, or `[AnyHashable:Any?]` to `[String:Any?]`, in this case.